# Jquery run function after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a table where I append table data. Part of that data is a checkbox. I need to check the box if the variable (inspectFall) has a 1 (checked). The below code works but seems messy with the .each() call. Is there a different way? Remember nothing is clicked, no even I can find is triggered (load, blur, etc). It calls the function to check the box. Thanks!

```
.append($('<td>').addClass('smallBox').append($('<input>', {'class': 'centerText', 'name': 'inspectFall', 'type': 'checkbox'}).each( function() { checkBoxes($(this), inspectFall); } )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to pass the object to your `checkBoxes()` function like this:

```
.append($('<td>').addClass('smallBox').append ($('<input>', checkBoxes({'class': 'centerText', 'name': 'inspectFall', 'type': 'checkbox'}))))
```

and then in your function you can extend and return the object if `inspectFall` has a 1 like this:

```
function checkBoxes(obj) {
  return inspectFall == 1 ? 
    $.extend(obj,{ "checked" : "checked" }): 
    obj;
}
```

or if you need the `inspectFall` variable to be passed as a parameter just add it to the function call like this:

```
.append($('<td>').addClass('smallBox').append ($('<input>', checkBoxes({'class': 'centerText', 'name': 'inspectFall', 'type': 'checkbox'}, inspectFall))))
```

and your function:

```
function checkBoxes(obj, inspectFall) {
  return inspectFall == 1 ? 
    $.extend(obj,{ "checked" : "checked" }): 
    obj;
}
```